Can you change your crew name?
Near the start of the campaign of Need for Speed Carbon on PS3, you are asked to pick a crew logo and name. Is it possible to change the crew name later on?

Found a post from a forum for the game saying you can. I don't have the game to test, but could you check if it is possible from the safe house page? Link
